# Kernel density estimation with reflection

Tags: r, kernel-smoothing

**EDIT:**

I try to decode the Silverman's reflection methods for the kernel density estimation using R. In my case, the lower boundary of the domain of a density to be estimated is set to 0 (zero).

As you know, the Silverman's book (`Silverman, B. W. Density Estimation for Statistics and Data Analysis. Monographs on Statistics and Applied Probability 26, Chapman & Hall/CRC, 1986`) illustrates two methods to correct the density estimate at the lower boundary. Those are described on page 31 and 32.

The online version of this book: http://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/March02/Silverman/Silver2_10.html

```
library(MASS)
data(Boston)
hprice <- Boston$medv
summary(hprice)

# The density is estimated at the values in x
x <- 0:40

# Silverman's bandwidth
n <- length(hprice)
IQR <- quantile(hprice,0.75)-quantile(hprice,0.25)
silverman.h <- 0.9*min(sd(hprice),IQR/1.349)*(n^-.2)

##########################################################################
############################# Method 1 ###################################
##########################################################################
hprice.r <- c(-hprice, hprice)
two.peaks <- density(hprice.r, from=-40, to=40, n=81, bw=silverman.h)$y
plot(-40:40, two.peaks, type="l")
hpdensity.reflection1 <- 2*two.peaks[41:81]
plot(x, hpdensity.reflection1, type="l")

##########################################################################
############################# Method 2 ###################################
##########################################################################
hpdensity.plus <- density(hprice, from=0, to=40, n=41, bw=silverman.h)$y 
hpdensity.minus <- density(-hprice, from=0, to=40, n=41, bw=silverman.h)$y

# What's happening in the negative side?
plot(x, hpdensity.minus, type="l")

# Density estimates = hpdensity.plus + hpdensity.minus
hpdensity.reflection2 <- hpdensity.plus + hpdensity.minus
plot(x, hpdensity.reflection2, type="l")

##########################################################################
####################### Compare the two estimates ########################
##########################################################################

cbind(hpdensity.reflection1, hpdensity.reflection2)[1:10,]
```

And the results are:

```
       hpdensity.reflection1 hpdensity.reflection2
  [1,]          1.209075e-05          1.161635e-05
  [2,]          4.332032e-05          4.313095e-05
  [3,]          2.094807e-04          2.079035e-04
  [4,]          7.111853e-04          7.093854e-04
  [5,]          1.792058e-03          1.787649e-03
  [6,]          3.583705e-03          3.580622e-03
  [7,]          6.060784e-03          6.059494e-03
  [8,]          8.852772e-03          8.856150e-03
  [9,]          1.127868e-02          1.128398e-02
 [10,]          1.315946e-02          1.315856e-02
```

I hope my code and result are of interest to researchers who have had experience of estimating the kernel density estimation. (I understand my posting does not interest you if you have never done some density analyses before.) Any comment or correction should be appreciated.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting you remove the link, though -- context helps, but your question should be able to stand on its own.